# PHP Heroku App Deployment using Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku

I have a PHP app hosted on Heroku using Mongo backend. I have followed the instructions on https://gist.github.com/pedro/1288447.

In my php.ini in my root folder I have 
`extension_dir = "/app/web/ext/"   extension=mongo.so`

My mongo.so is located in ext.

I have initialized my mongoclient with

```
    $mongo_url = getenv("MONGOLAB_URI");
    $m = new Mongo($mongo_url);
```

Doing `heroku config` shows that `MONGOLAB_URI:mongodb://heroku_app113736
7.mongolab.com:43477/heroku_app11373662`

However, the app still breaks whenever at `new Mongo(...)`: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mongo' not found`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try new MongoClient insteadof new Mongo

Comment: the error is related to the MongoDB PHP Extension it has nothing to do with the Mongo Server.

May be the mongo extension is not called "Mongo"

Comment: MongoClient produces the same class not found error.

Comment: So you created a /ext folder in your git repo and added the .so to the repository? And push it up every time? I'm started a new app, one weeks ago on heroku, and it's using mongo too. I now finished the basic database handling, and it's working like a charm. (I'm using FatFreeFramework, but still needed the mongo.so)

Comment: Yes on both accounts. I'm just hosting it on my own VPS now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions at https://gist.github.com/1288447

Custom extensions can be added to /app/www/ext/ with your custom php.ini!

change this :

```
getenv("MONGO_URL")
```

to this: (from the instructions in the link above)

```
getenv("MONGO_URI") // URI not URL just like in your code above.
```

Comment: Changed that, still the same error. I have noticed, however, that after I push the logs show `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/app/web/ext/mongo.so' - /app/web/ext/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0'.` I shouldn't be getting this because I did everything in link.

Comment: try 2 things :
1-make sure the file is in place, 2-give it 777 permissions or at least 755

Comment: I am an idiot. Stupid typo in the extension path that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

The env var has changed again.

Its now `MONGOHQ_URL` !

Answer (score 0):

Heroku needs Mongo PHP Client installed to run your app.

The proper way to install the extension is within `composer.json`

```
{
  "require": {
      "ext-mongo": "*"
   }
}
```

Then `composer update` and push the repo to heroku